# Can't get ONKEYDOWN and ONCHANGE events to fire for same input field in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I need the ONKEYDOWN to execute (JavaScript code is executed, right now just doing an alert), when that is complete I need ONCHANGE to execute if the value is changed (I tab off the field when I have finished changing the value to make this event fire.  This works fine in IE but I cannot get both to execute in Firefox.  Below is a simple example (no I cannot use onBlur). so I need to enter a value

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="TEST" MAXLENGTH="2" SIZE="3"
    ONCHANGE="alert('now in on onChange');"
    ONKEYDOWN="alert('in on keydown');"  VALUE="1"
>
```

In IE I change the value to 0, get 'in on KeyDown' alert, then I press tab get 'in on keydown' alert then 'now in onChange' alert.

In FF I only get the 'in on keydown' alert, never get now in onchange, any idea's how I can get this to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`alert()` messes things up in FF, use `console.log()` instead:

```
<input type="text" name="test" maxlength="2" size="3" value="1"
    onchange="console.log('now in on onchange');"
    onkeydown="console.log('in on keydown');"
>
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n6U9/).

Comment: I am actually calling javascript functions but put the alerts in to see what was getting executed and what wasn't.  I still can't get the onchange to fire after the onkeydown in firefox.

Comment: An error in the script for onchange? You can see onchange firing in the linked fiddle, also with FF. Is there any error messages in the console when running your script in FF?

Comment: no error in ff console when runing the script, just wont fire the onchange upon returning from onkeydown, sent a return true and a return false, also tried adding event.stopPropagation() before the return to see if the page would continue to process and it doesn't.  I can do the onchange function with no issues and I can comment it out and run just the onKeyDown with no issues.  When I put both in the same input, the onChange will not run.

Comment: Please add your original code to the question, or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), so we can try it.